# The sides of a triangle are $a,b,c$, which are integers, and $a\le b\le c$. If $c$ is given, find the number of triangles possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The sides of a triangle are $a$, $b$, and $c$ inches, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers and $a\le b\le c$. If $c$ is given, find the number of triangles possible.

I don't know from where to start this question. Please provide the solution.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of the cited question. That question asks for triangles where $a\le b\color{#C00}{\lt}c$.